# How do I use Boot Repair Disk?

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

Apologies. Total linux noob but I have been struggling trying to get Ubuntu to run for a couple of days now. I have read lots and tried lots of different things but I still can't get it to boot.

Windows XP loads automatically, without giving me the option to choose my OS.

I have tried to use Boot Repair Disk but I get a message that I have to use a Live USB but as far as I understand, I AM using a Live USB.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have your computer configured to boot from the DVD drive or USB stick that you have Ubuntu on.  When your computer first powers on, you press a special key to bring up the computer's boot menu.  Here's [a web page](https://www.desertcrystal.com/bootkeys) that can show you what key to press for your computer model.  Press that key several times when the computer first boots, and you should be taken to a menu that asks you if you want to boot from the hard drive, the DVD drive, or the USB device.  Pick the choice that has the Ubuntu live disk or live USB stick, and you'll soon be trying Ubuntu.  (The boot repair tool is a tool to use after something goes wrong with a Ubuntu installation, which is a fairly rare problem.)

Some computers have booting from any device other than the hard drive turned off in the BIOS, but this is fairly rare.  In that case you must go into the BIOS setup menus and configure your computer to allow booting from the DVD drive or your USB stick.  You get into the BIOS setup menus by pressing another key as the computer is first booting; the same web page I mentioned earlier will tell you which one.  In the BIOS setup menus you can also change the default boot order, so if you wanted you could make the computer always try to boot from the DVD drive or USB stick first, before trying to boot from the hard drive.  I wouldn't recommend that though, because if you leave a Windows DVD in the drive your computer could boot into the Windows installer by accident!  Yikes!

Good luck, and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken but I was hoping that having already installed Ubuntu, I would get a choice to boot Ubuntu or Windows when the computer starts up. I didn't think I would need to keep my USB stick in after installing. I have used the USB stick to try Ubuntu (in fact I am using it now). I am now wondering if I have installed it correctly.

Comment: So if I understand you right, you can boot to your live Ubuntu USB stick and try Ubuntu that way, but when you shut down and remove the live Ubuntu USB stick, then the computer boots right to Windows.  If that's the case, then Ubuntu probably wasn't permanently installed.  I seem to remember that there is an icon on the live Ubuntu desktop to permanently install Ubuntu to the hard drive.  Did you try that?

Comment: You were right. I think I only had the Live-USB version and hadn't actually installed it on the computer properly. I have now and it seems to be working well. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hey great, I'm glad you got Ubuntu installed, have fun with it!  Would you please consider marking my response as an answer to your question?